# iPhone Application Installation Link

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios, deployment

How can I make My iPhone Application's Installation Link ?

Description : I want to make an installation link of my iPhone Application. If I send a link to somebody ans when he/she clicks on the link , it directly ask for "Do you want to install the App?" and if yes then Installs the app on the Device.

Is there any way to do it ?

Thanks

EDIT : I didn't submit my app on the App Store. It's for my own. No App Store Submission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the Installing Apps Wirelessly section of [Distributing Enterprise Apps for iOS 4 Devices](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html) Enterprise documentation.

This will work for Enterprise Distribution but also for AdHoc if that device's UUID has been added to your adhoc provisioning profile.

Basically you can host your app binary on a webserver with some additional html & provision files and you point to that link from your other app.

The user will be asked if they want to install X from Y and then it will install if they agree.

There are several packaging tools out there to do this for you automagically. i.e. [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com/)

Comment: Thanks Koregan , I'll give TestFlight a shot as soon as I get time. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the link of your app on the app store

Comment: Please Look at the EDIT part.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create a jail broken application??

Create a distribution profile for your application, install it. 
Go to build menu, click on 'build and archive'.
Select 'share application'.
Enter the full path of the url for ipa file. 
You should get 'ipa' and a 'plist' file. Upload it. (same path mentioned in the url)
This should help.

Comment: I have problems in ipa and plist files. (First the organizer asks to give the path , then creates the files.)
After this where to upload ?

Comment: yes thats the catch, you first create a directory for those files on your server, so that your url is fixed and enter that same url in the organizer.

Comment: And yes I do think the iPhone will be jailbroken as it will downloading your app, which is not coming from the iTunes Store but from some other server. You please check on this part.

Comment: Thanks Vaibhav for the information. Will update soon as I get the things done.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do ad hoc distribution for beta testing and the like. You'll need the UUID of the phones that you want to install on to and then you can just provide a direct link to the .ipa file.

A quick google for iphone ad hc distribution will give you the methods to do this.