# inhouse iphone app distribution

Tags: iphone, distribution, enterprise

i have enterprise developer account.
Now i m having 2 queries
1. I m getting code sign error while i use this profile and requested certificate.
2. How to distribute app with this account - enterprise account

Reply asap
Thanks

Comment: See this thread-->[iphone-application-installation-link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102876/iphone-application-installation-link/5103024#5103024)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to distribute your app. One is to deliver the files (users will need both the app and a provision profile) to your users' computers by whatever means you like (e-mail, web server, thumb drive, etc.) and have your users install the app by dragging those files into their iTunes library. The other way is to host your app on a web server and distribute it directly to users' devices. Apple's [instructions for both methods are here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html).

It's hard to say what's causing your code signing error. What's helped me in the past is to read the error carefully for clues, and sometimes Google the exact error message. Make sure you've got your Entitlements file set correctly -- requirements for this seem to have changed at some point.

Comment: Hi Caleb, Thanks for your suggestion. For code signing error i have double checked request certificate and generated new Id and profile sitll have same prob, while app work f9 with other profile(other user request certificate and other profile). please help in this case

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way of deploying apps wirelessly which requires almost zero setup on your end (in case you don't want to spend the time needed for that) is to use something like [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com/).

Comment: This doesn't help on the code signing question. This is still required.